# Моргание чекбокса

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток !

Есть чекбокс, стилизован посредством `label`.

При наведении на чекбокс он один раз моргает, после его активации тоже один раз моргает, в чем проблема ?

```css
.checkbox {
  cursor: pointer
}

.checkbox:before {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  content: '';
  float: left;
  background: url(/img/svg/check_box_before.svg);
  margin: 0 7px 0 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px
}

.checkbox:hover:before {
  background-image: url(/img/svg/check_box_hover.svg)
}

.checkbox.on:before {
  background-image: url(/img/svg/checkbox_before.svg)
}

.checkbox.on:hover:before {
  background-image: url(/img/svg/checkbox_hover.svg)
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkID" name="checkID" value="false" />
<label for="checkID" class="checkbox " onclick="anonymousCheckbox(event, this)"><span></span>анонимно</label>
```

Comment: Какая версия браузера? В последнем Chrome и FF ничего не моргает.

Comment: @DogeDev, последний Яндекс.Браузер, сейчас посмотрю в другом браузере.

Comment: первый раз моргает из-за того, что подгружается другое изображение, потом уже картинка остаётся в памяти браузера, поэтому дальше не моргает

Comment: @fanfer, то есть это нормально ? А есть смысл сделать svg спрайт ?

Comment: svg-спрайты - нормальная практика. А стоит использовать или нет - это вам решать. Хотя в качестве фона проще, наверное, будет конвертировать svg в base64. [Например здесь](https://www.base64-image.de/)

Comment: @fnafer, я где то видел что говорят что не желательно кодировать svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Как убрать моргание чекбокса ?

---

Пошарив на английском стаке нашел [аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286745/css-avoid-image-hover-first-time-blinking).

Решение проблемы просто, нужно просто предзагружать `SVG`.

CSS:

```
body:after{
 display:none;
 content: url(/путь_до_файла/файл.svg);
}
```